# How can I generate Jaxb-XML-Beans from hibernate mapping file?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jaxb

I want to generate XML Jaxb-classes (like here [enter link description here](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/14-java-60-features-part-2-pluggable-annotation-proce-3.html)) from hibernate mapping file (hbm.xml). So is there a chance to do that with the hibernate-Tool hbm2java or do you think, that I should simpler do that with XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the POJOs that you are mapping with hibernate, then you can already use them with JAXB.  JAXB is configuration by exception which means you only need to add annotations where you want the mapping behaviour to differ from the default.

**For an Example**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, I have the mapping file, and the POJOs generated by hbm2java ...so now i've the problem to unmarshal the corresponding xml-Dokument...I would like to automatically unmarshall, so is there a need of annotation customization?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to convert hibernate objects to XML,you can try hibernate's feature to do that for you. You can provide both mappings in the hbm.xml itself. Please see link for more details.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html